# PHP dropzone instantiate with parameter settings

Tags: dropzone.js

Hi there I'm stumped by dropzone with PHP despite spending most of today trying to figure why others methods were failing.
I can get the basic dropzone on upload.php which takes files fine, but anything else like remove button or setting parameters dont work.

**index.php:**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <!-- 1 -->
<link href="dropzone.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
 
<!-- 2 -->
<script src="dropzone.min.js"></script>>
    </head>
    
<script type="text/javascript">
//NOTHING WORKS IN HERE
// The camelized version of the ID of the form element
Dropzone.options.myAwesomeDropzone = {
    maxFilesize: 1, // Size in MB
    addRemoveLinks: true,
      removedfile: function(file) { 
        var fileRef;
        return (fileRef = file.previewElement) != null ? 
          fileRef.parentNode.removeChild(file.previewElement) : void 0;
      }
                };
</script>

 
<body>
<!-- 3 -->
<form action="upload.php" class="dropzone"></form>   

 </body> 
</html>
```

**upload.php:**

```html
<?php
$ds = DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR;  //1
 
$storeFolder = 'uploads';   //2

if (!empty($_FILES)) {
     
    $tempFile = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];          //3             
      
    $targetPath = dirname( __FILE__ ) . $ds. $storeFolder . $ds;  //4
     
    $targetFile =  $targetPath. $_FILES['file']['name'];  //5
 
    move_uploaded_file($tempFile,$targetFile); //6
     
}
?>
```

Appreciate where I can be going wrong?